# Deploying go webapps to heroku: can't find package issue

Tags: heroku, go

I'm following [this tutorial](http://codegangsta.gitbooks.io/building-web-apps-with-go/content/deployment/README.html) and attempting to deploy a bare-bones Go web app to Heroku, but am having difficulties resolving an error:

`remote: -----> Running: godep go install -tags heroku ./...
remote: main.go:7:3: cannot find package "github.com/russross/blackfriday" in any of:
remote:     /app/tmp/cache/go1.3.3/go/src/pkg/github.com/russross/blackfriday (from $GOROOT)
remote:     /tmp/build_1a204a91c152b49fe234bde14529ad27/.heroku/g/src/bitbucket.gotest/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/russross/blackfriday (from $GOPATH)
remote:     /tmp/build_1a204a91c152b49fe234bde14529ad27/.heroku/g/src/github.com/russross/blackfriday
remote: godep: go exit status 1
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Go app`

I'm new to Go, so I assume I've screwed up my package structure, but running `$GOPATH/bin/godep go install` or `go install` works fine.

Here's the (abbreviated) structure of my go directory:

- src

  - testapp
  - main.go
  - github.com
    -codegangsta
  - russross
  - blackfriday

Thanks.

Comment: Go version 1.6 answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076898/go-app-on-heroku-with-local-packages/35494254#35494254

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the issue by adding my `$GOPATH/bin` dir to my path.

`export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin`

Curious as to why this was necessary, though.

Comment: Please fix the typo: "$GOAPTH/bin"